# Git 'nothing to commit, working tree clean'

Tags: laravel, git, github

Obtuve un proyecto de laravel por medio de `git clone`, hice una nueva branch para no modificar la original, pero al momento de dar `git commit` me marca:

```
nothing to commit
```

He checado y me encuentro en la carpeta correcta, ¿por qué no puedo hacer commit?

Comment: No se entendió muy bien, hiciste cambios?

Comment: Ejecuta el commando `git status` y dinos que ves.

Comment: antes de   hacer un `git commit` hicistes un `git add` ??

Comment: Si te sirve, me paso lo mismo y el error fue que no guarde los cambios antes de hacer commit. Lo dejo como comentario por si sirve par resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que no estás entendiendo bien sobre el tema de los branches en Git es que el hecho de crear un nuevo branch no es razón suficiente por sí misma para considerar que hay algún cambio en el proyecto. Tal vez con un ejemplo puedas enterdelo mejor. Probemos con un proyecto "test" y con un único archivo llamado "archivo.txt":

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/cesar/test/.git/
$ echo "¡No modificar este archivo en el branch master!" > archivo.txt
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    archivo.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ cat archivo.txt 
¡No modificar este archivo en el branch master!
$ git add .
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   archivo.txt

$ git commit -m "Primer release"
[master (root-commit) 21074dd] Primer release
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 archivo.txt
$ git branch 
* master
```

Muy bien, solo tenemos el branch `master` por ahora. Imagina que este es mi proyecto y tu lo clonas desde algún repositorio remoto (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.):

```
$ git clone ....
```

Decides crear un nuevo branch para no modificar el branch `master`:

```
$ git checkout -b paloma
Switched to a new branch 'paloma'
$ git status
On branch paloma
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Como puedes ver, tu "working tree" está limpio (porque no has modificado o agregado nada nuevo) y, por lo tanto no vas a poder hacer commit:

```
$ git commit -m "Mi branch"
On branch paloma
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Pero, ¿qué tal si modificas el archivo?:

```
$ echo " ¡Jódete jefe!" >> archivo.txt
$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   archivo.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Que se joda el jefe, he modificado el archivo en mi propio branch"
[paloma 81a5fa3] Que se joda el jefe, he modificado el archivo en mi propio branch
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git branch
  master
* paloma
```

Ahora sí, puedes hacer push y crear tu branch con tus cambios en el repositorio del cual has clonado previamente. Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Si creo que no había entendido muy bien eso de los branches y commit, pero ahora me ha quedado claro, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esto es porque debes agregar primero los archivos para dar commit.

**Para ver el estado de git usa:**

```
git status
```

**Para agregar TODOS los archivos "untracked" usas**:

```
git add .
```

SI, **git** luego la palabra **add** y luego **.** (punto) esto agregará absolutamente todo lo que tengas modificado, agregado o borrado.

**Para hacer commit**:

```
git commit -m "ESTO ES UN COMENTARIO ENTRE COMILLAS DOBLES"
```